# PHP - let user upload zip file and then do something with the contents

Tags: php, upload, zip, move, unzip

I would like to build in the following functionality to a script I am making:

- User uploads a zip file
- The server unzips it
- The server/PHP then takes the unzipped contents and puts them into different directories as specified in the script

For example, package.zip contains the following folders:

- folderA
- folderB

So when uploaded, is it possible to use PHP to unzip it, and then move the files into a specified directory, e.g:

- folderA >>>> Upload/Unzip/move to >>>> storage/folder-A-contents/
- folderB >>>> Upload/Unzip/move to >>>> storage/folder-B-contents/

If somebody could point me in the right direction it would be great. Or if someone knows it cannot be done, please say.

Thank you!

Comment: It is possible and not much complex. Check [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) and [The ZipArchive class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php)

Comment: @nigel may be you should look for some `file-manager` plugin using php and jquery... here is a free one..http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks - that looks like a useful link for me. Does any one know if the ability to upload and extract a zip file requires a special setting to be enabled in PHP? And if so, is this setting usually enabled or disabled by default?

Comment: You will need to enable `zlib` support in php. This is normally enabled in most of the installations. check phpinfo() if it is available.